# Convert data value to decimals?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function with an `argument` called `value`. This is used to pass the integer value of `value` to an array.

I want to take the value it returns and set it to two decimal places using toFixed(), but I am not sure at what point I can do this.

```
function getArrayOfItems(value, id, title) {
 return {
  Size: value
  };
};

var theData = [
            getArrayOfItems(data.average, 'average', 'Average'),
            getArrayOfItems(data.smallest, 'smallest', 'Smallest'),
            getArrayOfItems(data.largest, 'largest', 'Largest')
        ];
```

It eventually is passed to an object as such

```
var options = {
  amount: value,
  id: id,
  title: title
};
```

So the value is determined by the value of `data.average` etc, but it nearly always returns a 4 or 5 digit value. I want to parse this value to two decimal places. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.toFixed(2)` here

```
getArrayOfItems(data.average.toFixed(2), 'average', 'Average'),
getArrayOfItems(data.smallest.toFixed(2), 'smallest', 'Smallest'),
getArrayOfItems(data.largest.toFixed(2), 'largest', 'Largest')
```

as per another question

```
getArrayOfItems((data.average / 100).toFixed(2), 'average', 'Average'),
```

Comment: Thank you that's perfect. Is there a way to move the decimal place two places to the left? So instead of say 4500.00, as it now is, it becomes 45.00?

Comment: Supose 4545.00 what it returns

Comment: @Novocaine suppose 4545 it returns 45.45 its ok foreverlearning

Comment: @JqueryKing the second part of that answer does not work, the array is populating a chart and when I put in `(data.average / 100)` it won't render

Comment: @foreverlearning - I didn't know raise another question someone help you

Answer (score 0):

No sure if I understand the question correctly. But anyways maybe this will help:

```
function getArrayOfItems(value, id, title) {
 return {
  Size: (value).toFixed(2)
  };
}
```

or

```
var theData = [
            getArrayOfItems((data.average).toFixed(2), 'average', 'Average')

        ];
```